Out-of-sample forecast with SARIMAX
Goal: I want to train a SARIMAX (actually, an MA(1)-X) model on some training data (endog + exog) and then test it on new, test data. That is, once we have the coefficient for the error term in the MA regression, I want to do one-step ahead predictions on test data without retraining the model, basing the prediction only on the one-step-prior prediction vis-a-vis the new actual data. However, there seems to be no way of doing this in statsmodels, whose predict function doesn't ask for new endogenous data:
train_mask = xc.index < cutoff_date
xc_train, xc_test, yc_train, yc_test = xc[train_mask], xc[~train_mask], yc[train_mask], yc[~train_mask]

# Define the MA(1)-X model
model_ma1x = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(yc_train, exog=xc_train, order=(0, 0, 1))

# Fit the model
results_ma1x = model_ma1x.fit()

# Make predictions
pred_ma1x = results_ma1x.predict(start = yc_test.index[0], end = yc_test.index[-1] ,exog=xc_test)

# Plot the results
yc_test.plot(label='Actual', legend=True)
pred_ma1x.plot(label='Predicted', legend=True)
plt.title('MA(1)-X Model')
plt.annotate(f'R2: {r2_score(yc_train, pred_ma1x):.3f}', xy=(0.95, 0.05), xycoords='axes fraction', 
            ha='right', va='bottom', fontsize=9)
plt.show()

# Print the summary of the model
print(results_ma1x.summary())

This obviously gives me an error:

The start argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data.

Is there any way of achieving my goal?

Try a one-step-ahead forecast using the model pred = results_MA_model.get_forecast(steps=1, exog=exog_test).predicted_mean.iloc[0]

@Mario, thanks. This would only give one predicted data point. However, I want to predict over multiple periods, calculating the errors using actual test data. Hence, setting steps to greater than 1 wouldn't work, since the get_forecast function does not use new endogenous data

Then I would suggest using other TS-friendly packages for multi-step out-of-sampling forecasting.

BTW what do mean "SARIMAX (actually, an MA(1)-X) model on some training data (endog + exog)" is Moving Average Models (MA models) -X ? SARMIAX = MA(1)-X 1st order moving average - eXog?? can you reference the mathematic resource for it?

Did you also this title-related post?
